# Get current user in Umbraco version 7.3.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, umbraco

I'm trying to access the logged in Umbraco User, not member, but I cant get it work.

I have tried with the following methods but none work, they all return null:

```
umbraco.BusinessLogic.User.GetCurrent()
UmbracoContext.UmbracoUser
UmbracoContext.Security.CurrentUser
umbraco.helper.GetCurrentUmbracoUser()
```

I can access the user, for example Name, with the code below:

```
UmbracoContext.Application.Services.UserService.GetByEmail("name@company.com").Name
```

I have tried this code being logged in as a user and member, only user, only member and not logged in at all and it always returns the same result, null.

I have tried the code in a SurfaceController and UmbracoApiController with the same result. There is no problem getting the logged in member with `Membership.GetUser();` Has anyone else experienced this?

Using: Umbraco version 7.3.5 assembly: 1.0.5858.25602

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yeah I've tried to access the current backend user in numerous ways before and found the only way is to do:

```
var userTicket = new System.Web.HttpContextWrapper(System.Web.HttpContext.Current).GetUmbracoAuthTicket();
if (userTicket != null)
{
    var currentUser = ApplicationContext.Services.UserService.GetByUsername(userTicket.Name);
}
```

Comment: Worked flawlessly with one minor edit. Current seems to have been replaced so now I only used "var currentUser = ApplicationContext.Services.UserService.GetByUsername(userTicket.Name);"

Comment: Ah weird, it's working for me in 7.3.6 with that. But glad it helped! Just checked your version on 7.3.6 and it works as well so I've approved that edit.

Answer (score 5):

I have just yesterday implemented some code to get the current **user** using:

```
UmbracoContext.Current.Security.CurrentUser
```

That is not listed as one of the options you have tried?

Comment: Tried this as well but for some reason I don't get Current for UmbracoContext. The error I get is: "'UmbracoContext.Current' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead". I'm not trying to new it or anything like that, I get this error when I try it in Immediate Window as well.

Comment: What namespace is your UmbracoContext coming from?

Comment: @ProNotion You'll find UmbracoContext in namespace Umbraco.Web, check https://our.umbraco.com/apidocs/csharp/api/Umbraco.Web.UmbracoContext.html for more information.